# The gRPC object creates extra processes that don't close

Tags: python, ubuntu, multiprocessing, grpc

I developed the application with gRPC servicer. The point of my application is:

1. gRPC servicer (class DexFxServicer in the code below) has Transmit method which is called by gRPC client outside.
2. Transmit method creates multiple channels and stubs for the different hosts from hostList.
3. Further application creates the process pool and launches it.
4. Each child process calls gRPC method SendHostListAndGetMetrics for its own stub and receives response iterator.

This code works well, the application invokes Transmit method and receive all needed results from the process pool. But I noticed when outside gRPC client calls Transmit method multiple times, this code didn't close some of its child processes. And it leads to extra nonclosing processes creation as htop shows.
When I try to close gRPC channels by channel.close() method, extra processes are being created more intensively.

Python 2.7.12
grpcio==1.16.1
grpcio-tools==1.16.1
Ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS 4.4.0-143-generic

```
from concurrent import futures
import sleep
import grpc
import sys
import cascade_pb2
import cascade_pb2_grpc
import metrics_pb2
import metrics_pb2_grpc
from multiprocessing import Pool

class DexFxServicer(cascade_pb2_grpc.DexFxServicer):

def __init__(self, args):
    self.args = args

def Transmit(self, request, context):
    entrypoint = request.sender.host_address # entrypoint is a string
    hostList = []   # hostList is a list of strings
    for rec in request.sender.receiver:
        hostList.append(rec.host_address)

    channels = {}
    stubs = {}

    for host in hostList:
        try:
            channels[host] = grpc.insecure_channel('%s:%d' % (host, self.args.cascadePort))
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
            sys.exit(0)
        else:
            stubs[host] = metrics_pb2_grpc.MetricsStub(channels[host])

    def collect_metrics(host):
        mtrx = []
        hosts = (metrics_pb2.Host(hostname = i) for i in hostList + [entrypoint])
        for i in stubs[host].SendHostListAndGetMetrics(hosts):
            mtrx.append(i.mtrx)
        return mtrx

    pool = Pool(len(hostList))
    results = pool.map(collect_metrics, hostList)
    pool.close()
    pool.terminate()
    pool.join()

   # Return the iterator of the results
```

I expect to see the code which doesn't create extra nonclosing processes. Please, suggest me what to do in this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was solved by means of update grpcio version to 1.23.0. [gRPC issue](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/issues/20365)